# Test the convergence of the series-

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\frac{1\cdot 2}{3^24^2}+\frac{3⋅4}{5^26^2}+\frac{5⋅6}{7^28^2}+\cdots$$

I'm not able to calculate the correct result of the ratio test. It's resulting in the limit of 0.

Comment: The ratio test will result in a limit of $1$, which is inconclusive.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Well I'm not able to calculate the correct result of the ratio test in this problem.

Comment: The general term of the series is $a_n=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2n+1)^2(2n+2)^2}$.  Now have a look at the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and let $n\to\infty$.  The limit will be equal to $1$.  This means the ratio test is not conclusive.

Comment: Is this correct - $\frac{an+1}{an} = \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n+3)²(2n+4)²} • \frac{(2n+1)²(2n+2)²}{(2n-1)(2n)} = \frac{(2+1/n)(2+2/n) • (2+1/n)²(2+2/n)²}{(2+3/n)²(2+4/n)² • ((2-1/n)(2)} = \frac{2•2•4•4}{4•4•2•2} = 1$ . And apologies for not being able to format it in a good manner, it's my first time here. I didn't add limits as I don't know how to insert it here.

Comment: The first equality is correct and the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, that we can use comparison test:

$$\frac{2i(2i-1)}{(2i+1)^2(2i+2)^2} < \frac{(2i)^2}{(2i+1)^4}<\frac{1}{i^2}$$

Hence:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2i-1)2i}{(2i+1)^2(2i+2)^2}<
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you got zero, as the value of the limit during ratio test, that means the series is convergent. Because the limit result, has to be less than 1, for convergence. If it was equal to 1, you may have to use other tests.

Comment: This post seems to be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use *asymptotic equivalence*: the general term is
$$\frac{(2n-1)2n}{(2n+1)^2(2n+2)^2}\sim_\infty\frac{2n\cdot 2n}{(2n)^2(2n)^2}=\frac1{4n^2},$$
and the latter is convergent power series.